# Setup email@mydomain.com on LAMP server

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, lamp

I have a linode running Ubuntu 10.04, Apache2.2, etc... Late last night, finalizing some business cards I decided it would look more profesh if the email was info@mydomain.com rather than a gmail account. Now I'm faced with getting a mailserver set up and am not sure where to start. I've done a fair bit of sysadmin - not an expert but I get by. My question is this - what is the most sensible way to create an email address or two at my domain that will primarily handle incoming mail and that I'll bounce to my gmail account? Any helps appreciated.

Comment: you could either run a mailserver, which puts you at all sorts of risk for maintaining it (or paying for one somewhere) or you could use Google Apps. free, easy (just need to add a few MX records and an A for verification) and you can forward your mail or keep it there and check it as a second account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"what is the most sensible way"... I'd just use Google Apps for Domains if I was in your position.  Setting up a mailserver isn't rocket science, but you've presumably got better things to do than to learn how to do it.

On the other hand, if you really *do* want to setup your own mailserver... well, the questions in the "Related" sidebar of this question look useful, starting with [Setting up an Email Server on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/262/setting-up-an-email-server-on-ubuntu).

Comment: I'm not trying to manage a mailserver for fun - I just need my custom-looking email to point to an inbox somewhere. I'll look into google apps - thanks!

Comment: +1 for womble, Running your own mail server for yourself can get difficult, Google Apps has a great free edition and will save you a lot of hassle

Answer (score 1):

Maintenance of mail server is a continuous and complex task, especially spam protection.

> Personally i use postfix + amavisd-new + spamasassin + dcc + razor +
>   clamav + dovecot

For a cool business card self-hosted mail server is too much overhead. Many hosts include mail redirection services like those included in google apps for domains, for free.
First look at the company supporting DNS for your domain (where the NS records for your domain point)

```
host -t NS your.domain
```

http://www.emailaddresses.com/guide_forward.htm - example instruction for Mydomain.com

But of course, free service can be unreliable.